# Anaconda PyPi Installation

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install a package not build in conda on Python 3.5 but founded on PyPi:  *"Seasonal"*

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/seasonal

So I think I just have to do that :

```
conda skeleton pypi seasonal
conda build seasonal
conda install --use-local seasonal
```

It worked for an other one, but here I have this error :

```
((env-smart-data)) smartdata@smartdata-VirtualBox:~/PycharmProjects/TimeSerie$ conda skeleton pypi seasonal
Warning, the following versions were found for seasonal
0.3.1
0.3.0
0.2.0
0.1.0
0.0.0
Using 0.3.1
Use --version to specify a different version.
Error: Could not parse url for seasonal: UNKNOWN
```

So conda can find it, but there is a problem .. Any ideas ?

I've seen that seasonal is build on a Python 2.7, so I've tested it on a virtual env with Python 2.7, but it's exactly the same

Comment: Please click the `check mark` on the left side of my answer to accept it if it worked.

Comment: I'have to check if it works for my deployment before ;) if yes I click, If not I update my question ;)

Comment: Sure you are welcome :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find it on PyPi, then you can simply do this:

```
pip install seasonal
```

Since you have `conda` installed, `pip` called here is actually calling anaconda's `pip`. Thus it will automatically handle install path etc.

Comment: When i use conda list, my package is not installed

Comment: Yes because its installed in your site-libraries directory. However you can still import it as conda installed in your code.